# Composer + WAMP + Windows 8.1

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Hour's Googling and looking on here no-one seems to have had the exact issue.

In short:

- WAMP installed fine (error log empty)
- Composer installed fine (no errors during install)
- Windows PATH variable has the correct path the the composer /bin dir.
- Windows PATH variable also has the correct path to php

run > cmd

type composer

nothing... literally nothing. Just gives me another prompt (C:\user\whatever). Doesn't say "command not recognised" composer -v doesn't do anything.

Help! :)

Thanks
Joel

Comment: See if it works after you've restarted your PC.

Comment: Already tried thanks, still nothing :(

Comment: I have CYGWIN installed if that could cause any conflicts? Although I'm not using CYGWIN in this instance, just the usual cmd prompt

Answer (score 0):

Update: **** Knows what happened. Did nothing for two days and it just magically started working.

I must have tried re-starting 10 times, maybe a full system shut-down was required. Who knows... weird.

Comment: Update again - just realised i had to run composer first from the c:/wamp/bin/php5.5.12 directory. After that cd c:\ and it runs fine globally. Me being a tard.